# How to form POST message from several dialog menus?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have several pop-up menus (like modal menus in Bootstrap). I need to collect information from all of them ( user filling the first menu, after that he or she presses Next, first menu disappears and next menu appears and so on) and in the end user presses Submit on the last menu and passes the whole collected information on the server side. How can I collect information among menus on the client side?

Example of dialogs is here: http://jsfiddle.net/opustics/rftoafs2/1/

with 4 step-by-step menus:

```
<div id="test-modal-11" class="white-popup-block-big mfp-hide" style="text-align:center;">
<div id="test-modal-12" class="white-popup-block-big mfp-hide" style="text-align:center;">
<div id="test-modal-13" class="white-popup-block-big mfp-hide" style="text-align:center;">
```

and

```
<div id="test-modal-14" class="white-popup-block-big mfp-hide" style="text-align:center;">
```

Comment: you are saying on the client side, is it for a ajax call back to the server or... ?

Comment: apparently yes, I'm going to use the AjaxFormRequest(result_id,form_id,url, method)

Comment: Then the best way is on submit click to collect all of the data into a json object so you can send it along with the ajax call